# Rust config::builder::ConfigBuilder with static string source?

Tags: rust, config

I am using the Rust `config` crate and want to switch from loading configuration from a file at runtime to a static string created at compile time.

Right now, it works like this:

```rust
config::Config::builder().add_source(File::new("default.toml", FileFormat::Toml));
```

However when I try it with a static string, it does not:

```rust
static DEFAULT: &str = std::include_str!("./default.toml");
[...]
config::Config::builder().add_source(DEFAULT)
```

### Error Message

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: Source` is not satisfied
   --> src/config.rs:21:25
    |
21  |             .add_source(DEFAULT)
    |              ---------- ^^^^^^^ the trait `Source` is not implemented for `&str`
    |              |
    |              required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
note: required by a bound in `ConfigBuilder::<DefaultState>::add_source`
   --> /home/konrad/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/config-0.13.1/src/builder.rs:207:12
    |
207 |         T: Source + Send + Sync + 'static,
    |            ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `ConfigBuilder::<DefaultState>::add_source`
```

How can I read my config from a static string instead of a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`File::from_str()`](https://docs.rs/config/0.13.1/config/struct.File.html#method.from_str):

```rust
config::Config::builder().add_source(File::from_str(DEFAULT, FileFormat::Toml));
```